# Accessing the local storage in a QWebEngineView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, local-storage, qwebengineview

I am using `PyQt5` to display a web page with a `QWebEngineView` and I want to access the local storage of the current page (i.e. read the key-value pairs stored there).

I know that I can get the path where the local storage is located in a `level-db` on the hard drive like this:

```
browser = QWebEngineView()
localStoragePath = browser.page().profile().persistentStoragePath()
```

I am looking for an easier way without having to read the actual `level-db` manually. 
Is there a built-in option in `QWebEngineView`?